# VB.net Updating Datatable error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net, updates

I am trying to update the "qnty" column of a specific row in ds.Tables(0) but I don't know why this problem appear even though "qnty" in ds.Table(0) exist?

"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

I use VS 2012, VB.NET

```
Dim Minus_qnty As String
Dim Row() As Data.DataRow
Row = ds.Tables(0).Select("Prodno = '" & ProdItem_No & "'")                 
Dim ds_qnty As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("qnty").ToString()
Minus_qnty = ds_qnty + Prod_taken_qnty
Row(0)("qnty") = Minus_qnty 'The problem appear in this line
```

Comment: you have the column, but may not have any result from  `ds.Tables(0).Select`

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to check for row length

```
If Row.Length > 0 Then Row(0)("qnty") = Minus_qnty
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is not appering anymore but the "qnty" is still not updating

Comment: Well, if I've answered this question, then mark as answer. for updating please post another question with more detail on updating code.

Comment: Thank @Michael B. I analyze it yesterday and I already found what is the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there are no records in the DataTable matching your condition `Prodno = ProdItem_No`.

I think this is what you wanted to do:

```
    Dim Minus_qnty As String
    Dim Row() As Data.DataRow
    Row = ds.Tables(0).Select("Prodno = '" & ProdItem_No & "'")
    If Row.Length > 0 Then
        Dim ds_qnty As String = Row(0)("qnty").ToString()
        Minus_qnty = ds_qnty + Prod_taken_qnty
        Row(0)("qnty") = Minus_qnty
    End If
```

Or maybe simply this:

```
    Dim Row() As Data.DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Select("Prodno = '" & ProdItem_No & "'")
    If Row.Length > 0 Then
        Row(0)("qnty") = Row(0)("qnty") + Prod_taken_qnty
    End If
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this the error is not appearing now but "qnty" is still not updating

Comment: If you mean it is not updating in the database, then you are probably missing the `DataAdapter.Update` command. Updating anything in the DataSet doesn't imply that your back-end database will be updated automatically, since it is disconnected architecture.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my questions I analyze it earlier and I found already what is the problem. Again Thank You  :D